# Why isn't the text inside in my video background

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, video

I created a video background using this website as my reference

http://marketblog.envato.com/tips/video-background-html5-video/

and it seems to be working nicely to this point but I have one problem my text classes are not inside the video can anyone help please and thank you.

P.S. I'm using bootstrap 3

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="bgvid">
                <video autoplay loop muted poster="video.jpg">
                    <source src="480p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    <source src="480p.webm" type="video/webm">
                    </video>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <h1 class="content__heading">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
                                <p class="content__teaser">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                                <h2><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" id="arrow"></i></h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

html, body, div, h1, p, a, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}


#bgvid{
padding: 0;
}

#bgvid .content{
position: relative;
top: 30%;
z-index: 2;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 720px;
text-align: center;
}

.content__heading{
margin-bottom: 24px;
color: rgb(89,89,89);
}

#bgvid .content__teaser{
margin-bottom: 24px;
color: rgb(89,89,89);
}

html, body{
height: 100%
}

.video{
position: fixed;
top: 50%; left: 50%;
z-index: 1;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
width: auto; height: auto;
background: url(thelanguage.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

#arrow{
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? What do you want to achieve in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Your video class has a z-index of 1, so the text can be behind it, set your paragraph's z-index to a value higher than 1. And if you still don't see it, inspect the DOM and find that text. It has to be with either z-index or display/position combination.